# How to send to telegram's bot a signal to do something?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I had an idea to use `OnUpdate` to send a signal to the telegram's bot, but I need to detect which site sends the `Update` command to my bot.

How to accomlish that?

Comment: I need to do this because Telegram for some stupid reason blocked messsaging between bots.

Comment: Hi, [Ask]. It's a little bit short for a question.

Comment: And doenst the `e.Update.Message.Chat.Id` with `Telegram.Bot.Args.UpdateEventArgs e` work for that?

Comment: You can make external API do it outside of the bot